# How to estimate how big one number is from another?

Tags: python, numbers

I'm trying to find an efficient solution to this problem. I receive two numbers from an API call (we can call them n1, n2). Suppose n2 is bigger than n1. I want to know how much bigger n2 is. The difference between the two is not enough because I don't know how to evaluate the result of the subtraction. I don't see any other solution but to define a tolerance range that fits my domain of application and check if their difference falls within that range. Any idea?

Comment: Your question is specific to your requirements, which none of us know. Any answers you get are going to be pure guesswork as to your actual need. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just take the division?
Suppose n1 is 1 and n2 is 10.
If you divide n2 by n1 you will see that n1 is 10 times bigger than n2.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem when using floating-point, that results can be almost equal and you want to treat them as if they were equal.

You need a formula to measure the difference between the numbers relative to the size of the numbers, and it's remarkably tricky to find. One problem is avoiding division by zero.  As always, first check the libraries: in this case, the `math` module includes `math.isclose(a, b, *, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0)`

So let the mathematics experts handle it for you:

```
import math
if math.isclose(a,b):
    # they agree to around nine decimal places
```